# beautifulsoup and selenium: clicking on an svg path to get to the next page and get data from that page

Tags: python, selenium, svg, beautifulsoup, path

I'm working on a project where there is a table on a website that is filled with data, and the table is 7 pages long. it is the table on this website: https://nonfungible.com/market/history . You get to the next page through an svg path. I have to get data from all 7 pages. I don't know how to click on this svg path. Please let me know if you know how to click on the path.  even though the svg doesn't have an aria-label or a class.

this is a photo of the source code.

[image]

I have tried many different things including:

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="icon-chevron-right"]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="path"]').click()
```

this is the error that I am getting: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id="icon-chevron-right"]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="path"]"}
(Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.107)

Thank you for your help. please help me with this.

Comment: What errors do you have (also in most cases you'd get only one).

Comment: this is the error i get last:  selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@id="icon-chevron-right"]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="path] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@id="icon-chevron-right"]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="path]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error. And please format using `CTRL/CMD + K`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am unsure how to use CTRL + K formatting. Is it ok the way that it is? Thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: You can also use a "Code sample` button when editing

Comment: The clue is in the error. `InvalidSelectorException` - Your xpath is invalid. You're missing a `"` at the end of path: instead of `*[name()="path]` try  `*[name()="path"]`

Comment: thank you!! I just changed it and it is giving me a new error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly different approach than using the GUI - but have a look at the below. Doing it this way offers much more data than the front end shows.

It looks like the `/market/history` page comes down with the JSON data (it's not a separate call in can identify in dev tools).
However - if you:

1. Get the page with the python `requests` library
2. Parse the html and find the json data object which is `@id="__NEXT_DATA__"`
3. Get the right part of the json which has the table data
4. Filter the object to get rid of a few bits and pieces (where `name != none`)

```py
from lxml import html
import requests
import json

url = "https://nonfungible.com/market/history"

#get the page and parse
response = requests.get(url)
page = html.fromstring(response.content)

#get the data and convert to json
datastring = page.xpath('//script[@id="__NEXT_DATA__"]/text()')
data = json.loads(datastring[0])
#print(json.dumps(data, indent=4)) #this prints everything

#Get the relevant part of the json (it has lots of other cr*p in there - it was effort to find this
tabledata = data['props']['pageProps']['currentTotals']
# this filters out some of the unneeded data
AllItems = list(filter(lambda x: x['name'] !=None, tabledata)) 

#print out each item - which relates to an row in the table 
for item in  AllItems:
    print (item['name'])
    print (item['totals']['alltime']['usd'])
    print (json.dumps(item, indent=4))
```

What you need to do from here is extract what you want from the json.

I've started you off...
The first 2 prints in the loop output this:

> meebits
>
> 157251919.08

Which match the items on the website:
[image: website image highlighted]

The last print does this is everything that item has. This will let you see the structure and help you get your data out. It looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "meebits",
    "totals": {
        "alltime": {
            "count": 15622,
            "traders": 5023,        
            "usd": 157251919.08,    
            "average": 10066.06,    
            "transfer_count": 29826,
            "transfer_unique_assets": 19981,
            "asset_unique_owners": 4812,
            "asset_usd": 95541331.68,
            "asset_average": 10566.39
        },
        "oneday": {
            "count": 0,
            "traders": 0,
            "usd": 0,
            "average": 0,
            "transfer_count": 0,
            "transfer_unique_assets": 0,
            "asset_unique_owners": 0,
            "asset_usd": 0,
            "asset_average": 0
        },
        "twodayago": {
            "count": 0,
            "traders": 0,
            "usd": 0,
            "average": 0
        },
        "sevenday": {
            "count": 144,
            "traders": 165,
            "usd": 703913.21,
            "average": 4888.29,
            "transfer_count": 265,
            "transfer_unique_assets": 204,
            "asset_unique_owners": 125,
            "asset_usd": 611620.92,
            "asset_average": 5412.57
        },
        "thirtyday": {
            "count": 1663,
            "traders": 1167,
            "usd": 12662841.8,
            "average": 7614.46,
            "transfer_count": 2551,
            "transfer_unique_assets": 1704,
            "asset_unique_owners": 781,
            "asset_usd": 9908945.2,
            "asset_average": 9107.49
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. This is so nice and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using your browser's developer tools to see what request is made to the site and then make the same one from your script. That eliminates the need for selenium and should get you a more scalable bot.