# Selenium and Chromedriver on Lambda - Inconsistency at scale

Tags: selenium, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless, aws-lambda-layers

I have a basic selenium script running/deployed on aws lambda.
Chrome and chromedriver and installed as layers (and available on /opt) via serverless.

The script **works** ... but only some of the time and rarely at scale (invoking more than 5 instances asynchronously).

I invoke the function in a simple for loop (up to about 200 iterations)

```
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:12345667:function:selenium-lambda-dev-hello',
    InvocationType='Event',  #|'RequestResponse'|'Event' (async)| DryRun'
    LogType='Tail',
    #ClientContext='string',
    Payload=event_payload,
    #Qualifier='24'
)
```

Other runs, the process hangs while initiating the selenium driver on this line

```
            driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver_89', chrome_options=options)
```

other iterations the drivers fail/throw a  'timeout waiting for renderer exception'
This I believe is often due to a mismatch of chromedriver/chrome.  I have checked and verified my versions are matched up and compatible (and like i said they do work sometimes).

I guess i'm looking for some ideas/direction to even begin to troubleshoot this. I was under the impression that each invokation of a lambda function is in a separate environment, so why would increasing the volume of invokations have any adverse effect on how well my script runs?

Any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated all!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: My gut reaction is that selenium is for GUI testing. Chrome is memory and processor hungry, heavy and slow. You could find that your memory allocated in lambda isn't enough. I totally get this doesn't answer your question - as an option to removing the selenium errors - does your script need to go down the selenium/chrome path?  - Can you do the equivalent with an API library like `requests` and `lxml`? - i've reworked such scripts recently and can potentially help if needed.

Comment: Thanks @RichEdwards,  I have bumped up the memory allocation in lambda to max this out, and things have indeed improved!  I'm going to continue looking into better alterantatives, unfortunately for this solution we have a need to maintain the session and perform some actions/track where the browser ends up.

Comment: Glad it helped! If you're tied to using GUI, Do you have to use chrome? If you're not functional testing then consider another headless browser like `phantomjs` or the light weight `htmlunit` driver?   - something that doesn't need a seperate driver, doesn't need an installed application...  I know Lambda is cheap - but it's pay by the milisecond and memory. If you can shave off 50% of your execute time you'll save 50% off your bill  (and potentially fix your stability issues)

Answer (score 0):

Discussed in the comments.

There's no complete solution but what has helped improve the situation was increasing the memory of the Lambda service.

The alternatives to try/consider:

1. Don't use Chrome. Use `requests` and `lxml` to query the pages via the network level and remove the need for Chrome.

I did something similar to support [another stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68560775/beautifulsoup-and-selenium-clicking-on-an-svg-path-to-get-to-the-next-page-and/68572934#68572934) recently. You can see it's similar but not quite the same.

Go to a url and get some text from an xpath:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import json
url = "https://nonfungible.com/market/history"

response = requests.get(url)
page = html.fromstring(response.content)
datastring = page.xpath('//script[@id="__NEXT_DATA__"]/text()')
```

2. Don't use Chrome. Chrome is ideal for functional testing - but if that's not you objective consider using `HtmlUnitDriver` or `phantomjs`. Both of these are significantly lighter than chrome and won't require a browser to be installed (you can run it straight from libraries)

You only need to change the driver initialisation and the rest of the script (in theory) should work.

PhantomJS:

```
$ pip install selenium
$ brew install phantomjs
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

Unit Driver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Remote(
  desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT)
```

Comment: Thank you rich!  I was under the impression that phantomjs was more of a memory hog than chrome from this article https://hackernoon.com/benchmark-headless-chrome-vs-phantomjs-e7f44c6956c

Using the requests lib is definitely a more efficient way to do it,  the problem is that for my use case, it requires maintaining a user session (while a waiting queue timer runs)  and then tracking where the redirect takes the user afterwards.  Not sure this would be possible with the requests lib?

Comment: Probably not for requests. Requests doesn't subscribe to anything and doesn't run JS. I expect this specific feature is powered by js. Either the js tracks your time on a specific page with no action and tells the server you're inactive (and redirects you) or the js sends a heartbeat to the server and after so many beats(/time) the sever says kick... Either way - needs js.